# ajax error in calling a method in asp.net via post and having a lengthy argument size

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, vb.net

Good morning, the problem is that I am calling a web method ( **ASP.NET VB.NET** ) via ajax ( **jquery** ) and jquery makes the call to the web method returns an internal server error , the parameter that receives a html that will be processed on the server, when I send some little string like " Hello World" works great , but if I send the html does not work , this is the jquery code:

```
 $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "url.aspx/webmethod",
                dataType: "json",
                data: '{param1: "' + @param1 + '"}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                beforeSend: function () {

                },
                success: function (response, status, xhr) {

                    alert("Success")
                },
                error: function (error, status, ethrow) {
                    alert("Error")
                },
                complete: function () {

                }

            })
```

length of html data: **75825**

VB.NET CODE:

```
<WebMethod()> _
    Public Shared Function webmethod(ByVal param As String) As String

    return param
    End Function
```

When I pass the html never comes to vb.net

Comment: Check `web.config` for `maxrequestlength` or `maxAllowedContentLength`, and try increasing that value to make this work.

Comment: i have this in the web config:

 `<webServices>
        <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="900000000"/>
      </webServices>

<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" executionTimeout="600" maxRequestLength="900000000" appRequestQueueLimit="1000" />

    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="9000000" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>

<add key="aspnet:MaxJsonDeserializerMembers" value="50000000000"/>`

Comment: I told you to increase that value or else post that value here!

Comment: The value is placed on the comment above.. the value is
maxRequestLength = " 900000000 "

maxAllowedContentLength = " 9000000 "

Comment: I forgot one this, you also need to increase execution time out - http://forums.asp.net/t/1040377.aspx?How+to+increase+the+time+out+for+request+response+ , as this upload process will take some time , if timeout is less, it will give up and show error.